# Issues in tabbar title in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, title, tabbar

Currently i am working in iPhone app, i have four screen like Login, A,B and c etc..
User enter the username and password field in login screen, then press login button

```
-(void)LoginButtonMethod
{

    A *a = [[A alloc]init];
    B *b = [[B alloc]init];
    C *c = [[C alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *navi1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:a];
    UINavigationController *navi2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:b];
    UINavigationController *navi3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:c];

    UITabBarController *TabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    TabBar.delegate = self;
    TabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navi1, navi2, navi3, nil]; 
    navi1.tabBarItem.title=@"A";
    navi2.tabBarItem.title=@"B";
    navi3.tabBarItem.title=@"C";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:TabBar animated:YES]; 
}
```

Then i have set navigationbar title for each class like A as facebook, b as yahoo, c as google.

Finally i run the application, tabbar title showing in A,B,C
Then i select 3rd tabbar item (C), at the time that tabar title change google.
i can't fix this, please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: ia ma confused, do you want 3rd name (C as per you) to come as google or not?

Comment: Have you set self.title = @"Your Title" in View Did Load for each controller may be this will solve your problem.

Or you can add only for ViewController where you are facing problem

Comment: This should work check through breakpoints in both classes.

Answer (score 0):

Apple in it's developer documentation states following:

```
    "You never want to push a tab bar controller onto the navigation stack of a navigation controller. Doing so creates an unusual situation whereby the tab bar appears only while a specific view controller is at the top of the navigation stack. Tab bars are designed to be persistent, and so this transient approach can be confusing to users."
```

try presenting it

```
[self presentModalViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push Tabbar to Controller By

**Either**

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
```

**or**

```
[self presentModalViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
```

Hope this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

in this

`- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil`

Method of each view Controller put the following code..

```
self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Comment" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-AddComment.png"] tag:0];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Comment";
```

it Works